# How to advertise admob without google market

Tags: android, admob

I created an android app with Admob advertisement.
I don't want to publish my app on Google market. And my user still use my app. 
can I get payment from Admob?
Anyone have experience with that, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need to publish your App on the Play Store (new name of the Google Market) and still get payed from Admob because it is an Play Store independent Service from Google. All you need is an Admob account and advertisment impressions generated on your app. You could send out your App by E-Mail for installation or even upload it to the Amazon Market or any other Market App. Also uploads to multiple different Markets are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You still get payment from admob without put it on playstore. Its individual feature provided by Google. But, why wouldn't you upload your app to Google Play - it is a very large market that you will be missing out on?